# Should I choose easy modules?

Tags: university

So I'm in my third year of university and I'm at the point where I have to choose my modules for next year. This is a simple question, but I really wish I asked it a long time ago because I have no idea of the answer.

Should I pick modules I know I can easily pass that will get me a better final grade but probably won't teach me anything **OR** should I pick modules that will be more challenging for me, will give me a lower final grade than if I picked the easy ones but with the benefit of teaching me a great deal?

I suppose at the root of it the question is am I at university solely to strengthen my future career prospects or am I here for the purpose of learning. Regardless of my answer to that, I'd like to know what people advise regarding module picking.

Bare in mind that I don't say "easy" modules because they're easy but because I practice a lot of the required skills in my free time so I have experience. They will still have the same value as the hard modules if an employer were looking at them.

Comment: This may be obvious, but the answer is it depends. My undergraduate university had some courses aimed at math PhDs that were open to undergrads. Any undergrad who dared take them did really badly. In my final year only one of the undergrads who took one particular course achieved a passing grade. We all learned a lot, but I still have a fail on my transcript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that the "easy" courses are the ones in which you already have experience. If you take those classes, the course work will be redundant and will not boost your knowledge. On the other hand, it seems that you are also concerned about your overall GPA.

Ask yourself what you want to do. Then look for classes that come under the umbrella of 'what I want to do'. Eliminate the courses from that umbrella that fall into the "easy" bucket and the "very tough" bucket (which might dampen your GPA) and pick from among the rest.

Comment: Sounds like a [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) needs to be drawn `;)`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Go neither for easy nor for challenging courses but for courses that **interest you the most**.

Comment: I like this answer, but tell me why I should pick courses that interest me the most over courses that would strengthen a future profession in a related field and teach me a lot?

Math at sixth form (ages 16-18 optional courses in the UK) never interested me but if I didn't pick it my career path would be hugely limited and would've made my CV/Résumé a lot weaker.

Comment: The way I see it, you have two options: go down the "money" path, taking sure-choices that might not interest  you and you might force yourself to do them, but will give you an edge at getting better grades, jobs, and salaries. But that way you risk ending up at a job you don't like, that seems like necessary everyday torture. Or you could go and do what you like even if you can't make money as easily. End up doing something that's your passion, enjoying your work and what you have. And eventually become good enough in what you are passionate about that people will pay well for your expertise.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to do afterwards? Academia or industry? What is your field? From what you say, "easy" modules would be the ones that interest you, so taking them will mean having formal training and proven experience. On the other hand, certain skills can be proven in many ways (you can show you know how to program by making contributions in open software projects). The formal training will allow you to get a much deeper understanding of the topic, provided the teaching and the course are good, of course.

The question is what is more valuable? Wide range of skills or deep knowledge of a few?

And yet another point to consider is how are your grades so far. Consider if you can afford loosing a few points, and what difference it will make. Perhaps the difference between a class 1 and 2.1 is bigger than a 2.1 and a 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a country that only cares about GPA (for things that aren't internships) then no fault to you if you try to maximize GPA. However, your goal should be to be exposed to as much theory as possible, with the highest difficulty possible; while aiming to understand and be able to **use** just a small fraction of that. The more you can **use**, (i.e. practically) the better. GPA can be quite useless.

Take the hardest courses you can without failing out of your program. Study such that (while you may not do well on tests), you'll remember this stuff *after* you graduate.